# How do I determine my gem's required ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am creating a gem and I have the suspicion that it may not work on certain Ruby versions. Is there a way to quickly check which Ruby versions it is compatible with? My current method is using RVM and switching to different Ruby versions to test, but that may be an inefficient way to do it. I was also wondering if I could narrow it down to a specific patch version.

Comment: Use a CI tool and build out a matrix of ruby versions to test against.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Schuchard suggested the right way to do this (in the comment)

For example, you can check how to do this with GitHub Actions. You can test it not only for specific ruby version but also on different OSes

https://github.com/metanorma/metanorma/blob/master/.github/workflows/rake.yml